# C++ "destructive procedural variant" results in prior version of binary search tree being lost

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, reference, binary-search-tree

I've been reviewing C++ pointers and references and want to verify I understand what's meant by "destructive procedural variant" here in the following example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion):

> Here's how a typical binary search tree insertion might be performed in a binary tree in C++:
>
> ```
> Node* insert(Node*& root, int key, int value) {
>   if (!root) 
>     root = new Node(key, value);
>   else if (key < root->key)
>     root->left = insert(root->left, key, value);
>   else  // key >= root->key
>     root->right = insert(root->right, key, value);
>   return root;
> }
> ```
>
> The above *destructive* procedural variant modifies the tree in place.
>   It uses only constant heap space (and the iterative version uses
>   constant stack space as well), but the prior version of the tree is
>   lost.

Is the point here (no pun intended) that there might be other copies of the "root" pointer that will still point to a NULL value when our pointer here gets referenced to a new Node object?

If yes, then why use the words "the prior version of the tree is lost"? (Wouldn't a simple solution to this in C++ be to make sure nobody stores a pointer to a NULL binary tree, or to make sure they store a reference to the root pointer rather than a copy of it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down in the Wikipedia entry, the behavior of Python is noted as a contrasting example. There, you see that 'adding' a node to a tree actually creates a new tree with the extra node. So the tree prior to the call to insert can still be referenced in this case.

However, in the C++ example, the tree structure is changed when a new node is inserted and the previous state is lost.

Comment: Thanks Mikel. I see their reference to [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), makes sense now.